# Python formula syntax

Tags: python, api, error-handling, syntax, formula

New to working with python and API's. Having difficulty creating a formula that involves numbers and variables. The variables were created using information (values, ex. available_balance = 4500, but 4500 is not a fixed number and is constantly changing) from trading website.

```
# Retrieving and printing values for available_balance and last_price
print('Available Balance: ')
print(session.get_wallet_balance(coin="USDT")['result']['USDT']['available_balance'])
print('Last Price: ')
print(session.latest_information_for_symbol(symbol="BTCUSDT")['result'][0]['last_price'])

# Assigning variables representing the value of available_balance and last_price
lastPrice = (session.latest_information_for_symbol(symbol="BTCUSDT")['result'][0]['last_price'])
availableBalance = (session.get_wallet_balance(coin="USDT")['result']['USDT']['available_balance'])

# Verifying values are properly assigned to variables
print()
print('Last Price and Available Balance:')
print(lastPrice, availableBalance, sep='\n')

# Order Size formula = last_price * available_balance * leverage * perc (ex. 100% = 1, 25% = 0.25) * (1-(0.00075) * 2)

orderSize = lastPrice * availableBalance * 15 * 100 * (1-(0.00075) * 2))
print(orderSize)
```

Error received was:

```
orderSize = lastPrice * availableBalance * 15 * 100 * (1-(0.00075) * 2)
```

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'.

Any help would be great! I added the request example/response from Bybit's API:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOIRM.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4XFJ.png)

Comment: That indicates that `availableBalance` is not a number, but a list. You should find out by debugging, and reading the wallet API documentation.

Comment: it just says that either `lastPrice` or `availableBalance` are arrays. It might be the case that one of them is returned in the form `[500]` for example. Could you please add the output of the last print statement before the error?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 1):

The ***Type Error*** : [ **can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'** ] indicates that there was a attempt that you are trying to **multiply a floating datatype to a list ones...**.

You have to check What Was The Type Of **lastPrice** and **availableBalance**, One of them should return a **seq** which cant be multiplied with a **float**.

Hope It Helps Buddy ;)

Comment: Added pics of the API from Bybit, not too sure to be honest.